# Bitwise Comparison to establish Bit Shift

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit-shift

We are dealing with a SerDes system with a high throughput. To ensure word alignment, I need to estimate the number of bits we need to bitslip.

For example if the input is 14'b 11111110000000 but the decoded output is 14'b 01111111000000 then clearly we need to bitslip by 1 bit.

Due to the timing constraints on this we cannot afford the time to iterativly shift and compare.

Is there any simple (single clock cycle) bitwise comparison can can estimate the number of bits we need to slip, perhaps XOR etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not single cycle, but can you count trailing zeroes? (can be replaced by popcnt)

Comment: Can you afford a table lookup?

Comment: It looks like bitwise XOR with the expected word framing signal, with a summation and division by 2 is suitable. By pipelining this, the estimation of bit slip can operate at the same DIVCLK as the serDes output. For example 14'b 11111110000000 XOR'ed with a 2 bit shifted version 14'b 00111111100000, becomes 11000001100000, the bitwise sum of this is 4, so simple bitshift division by 2 yields 2, i.e. the correct bitshift needed. This works for all 8 shifts for a 8 bit framing word of the forb 8'b11110000, so hopefully it is suitable.